# java constructor SimpleAdapter in class SimpleAdapter cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, xml-parsing

Java constructor `SimpleAdapter` in class `SimpleAdapter` cannot be applied to given types when I write the line I mention it below why and how can I solve this error.

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private Exception exception;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            //Invoke webservice
            displayText = WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS(spin2, spin3, spin1, "search_availability");
            ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

             menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            XmlParser parser = new XmlParser();
            String xml = null; // getting XML
            try {
                xml = parser.getXmlFormUrl(URL);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID,  parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
                map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);
            }
            // Adding menuItems to ListView
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


        //Set response
        tv.setText(displayText);
        //Make ProgressBar invisible
        pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Make ProgressBar invisible
        pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }

}
```

**at this lines**

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });
```

I don't know why this error occurs and how do I solve this error.

Comment: `this` is not a `Context` instance in your case but an instance of `AsyncCallWS`

Comment: how can i solve it

Comment: @Blackbelt please help me i am beginner with android and java

Comment: Replace `this` with something that is a `Context`. If the outer class to `AsyncCallWS` is an `Activity` you can use `YourActivityName.this`. If it is a `Fragment` use `getActivity()`.